# Set dynamic cost according to browser location in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, location

I am adding dynamic local currency on products.

In US, *Product A is of $1.*

In India, *Product A is of 75rs.*

All i need is, i want to know currency from location (from where browser is opened) in reactJS to handle the dynamic change in currency of rates.

My Findings -

I found this API -
http://ip-api.com/json?fields=status,country,currency

But Axios was throwing ERROR, **(blocked:mixed-content)**

As it accepts `https` instead of `http`. And `https` is **not** free here (ip-api.com)

Is their any other way to achieve the currency via browser OR can we fix that https thing which i specified above ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options: the browser-native interface `fetch`  or another popular HTTP library called `request`.

Comment: You are doing something wrong then. Could you please accept the answer?